# How to read a grid from $0200 to $05ff in 6502 Assembly

Tags: 6502

So I've been given an assignment where we have to make a symbol using colored pixels using an 6502 assembly emulator. I don't quite understand how this grid works. Could someone please explain how this grid works and maybe give and example?

here is the link to the emulator: https://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/#first-program

and the grid I'm to work with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuqPi.png

Comment: As far as I can tell, that 1kB of memory corresponds to a 32x32 pixel bitmap where each byte represents one pixel (with only the lower 4 bits of each byte being used). I'm not sure what else there is to explain. The page you linked to even has some code filled in which plots a couple of pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Michael's command is correct; avoiding use of 'x' and 'y' for potential register ambiguity reasons, address `$0200 + (q*32) + p` contains the pixel at (p, q) for p and q in the range 0 to 31, and in each byte the low four bits determine the pixel colour.

So e.g. `$0200` is the pixel in the top left, `$0201` is the pixel one to the right of the top left, and `$0220` is the pixel one below the top left.

In 6502 terms one possible straightforward implementation of a generic plot subroutine could use indexed indirect addressing, storing `$0200 + (q*32)` into a zero-page location and then indexing by `p` to hit a particular horizontal position within that row. Off the top of my head, and without having checked exactly what syntax that assembler uses and hard-coding the use of zero-page addresses $80 and $81:

```
; 
; Plot; stores the colour in A to the pixel at (y, x).
; So, yes: x and y are backwards.
;
; Clobbers x.
;
Plot:
    ; Arbitrarily, this adds x to ($200 >> 5) and
    ; then shifts the whole lot left by 5. That's
    ; rather than shifting x by 5 and then doing a
    ; one-byte add to the upper byte, I guess.

    pha
    txa
    clc
    adc #$10 ; $10 = $200 >> 5
    sta $80
    lda #$00
    sta $81

    ; Multiply by 32. You could unroll this if
    ; that's what your priorities imply.
    ldx #5
.rollLoop
    asl $80
    rol $81
    dex
    bne rollLoop

    pla
    sta ($80), y

    rts
```